# Determine if icon is being used

Tags: icons, ubuntu-mate

I saw this icon `hb-icon.svg` in `/usr/share/app-install/icons/`

And it is 3.4 Mb !!

Why is an icon so big?

Can I tell if it is being used so if it isn't, I can delete that monster?

Comment: It's generally not advisable to mess with or delete package-provided files. Also, 3.4MB is relatively big for a simple icon, but it's really nothing in comparison to other files. We're not in the age of floppies any more anyway. I'd just leave it alone, not much to gain from it but plenty to screw up (not exactly with that icon, probably, but in general)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not safe to delete. It's part of the `app-install-data` package, which is needed by several other important packages.

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ ll /usr/share/app-install/icons/hb-icon.svg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3416277 Sep  9  2015 /usr/share/app-install/icons/hb-icon.svg
walt@bat:~(0)$ file /usr/share/app-install/icons/hb-icon.svg
/usr/share/app-install/icons/hb-icon.svg: SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image
walt@bat:~(0)$ display /usr/share/app-install/icons/hb-icon.svg
walt@bat:~(0)$ dpkg -S /usr/share/app-install/icons/hb-icon.svg
app-install-data: /usr/share/app-install/icons/hb-icon.svg
walt@bat:~(0)$ apt rdepends app-install-data
app-install-data
Reverse Depends:
  Depends: software-center (>= 0.4.0)
  Suggests: apt-xapian-index
  Depends: jasper
  Depends: lubuntu-software-center
  Suggests: apt-xapian-index
  Depends: sessioninstaller
walt@bat:~(0)$
```

If you're at the point where deleting a 3.3M file is starting to look like a Good Idea, you're not solving the right problem - why don't you have enough disk space, and where don't you have it?

Comment: I will leave the file. I have plenty of disk space. I use about 80 mb on a 2 Tb drive. But that is not my point. I am scientist and I like learning. I see no issue with trying to improve things.That is one way that things get better. :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [search on codesearch.debian.net](https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=hb-icon.svg) this icon is related to [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/).

Search on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=hb-icon.svg) confirms this. So it simply great and pretty icon scalable SVG icon of Handbrake.

Both icons in `/usr/share/app-install/icons/hb-icon.svg` and `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/hb-icon.svg` have identical MD5 sums. So really the icon may be removed from `/usr/share/app-install/icons/hb-icon.svg` without problems.

But the icon itself looks very nice, elegant and detailed (1658 x 1721 pixels)

[image: Handbrake]

The removal will not save much space. So I'll recommend to save it :)

Comment: Since you found out it is not needed, I may have to delete it. :-)